# R - How to get one "summary" prediction map instead for 5 when using 5-fold cross-validation in maxent model?

Tags: r, maps, prediction, cross-validation, maxent

I hope I have come to the right forum. I'm an ecologist making species distribution models using the maxent (version 3.3.3, http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/) function in R, through the dismo package. I have used the argument "replicates = 5" which tells maxent to do a 5-fold cross-validation. When running maxent from the maxent.jar file directly (the maxent software), an html file with statistics will be made, including the prediction maps. In R, an html file is also made, but the prediction maps have to be extracted afterwards, using the function "predict" in the dismo package in r. When I do this, I get 5 maps, due to the 5-fold cross-validation setting. However, (and this is the problem) I want only one output map, one "summary" prediction map. I assume this is possible, although I don't know how maxent computes it. The maxent tutorial (see link above) says that:

"...you may want to avoid eating up disk space by turning off the “write output grids” option, which will suppress writing of output grids for the replicate runs, so that you only get the summary statistics grids (avg, stderr etc.)."

A list of arguments that can be put into R is found in this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maxent/yRBlvZ1_9rQ.

I have tried to use the argument "outputgrids=FALSE" both in the maxent function itself, and in the predict function, but it doesn't work. I still get 5 maps, even though I don't get any errors in R.

So my question is: How do I get one "summary" prediction map instead of the five prediction maps that results from the cross-validation?

I hope someone can help me with this, I am really stuck and haven't found any answers anywhere on the internet. Not even a discussion about this. Hope my question is clear. This is the R-script that I use:

model1<-maxent(x=predvars, p=presence_points, a=target_group_absence, path="//home//...//model1", args=c("replicates=5", "outputgrids=FALSE"))

model1map<-predict(model1, predvars, filename="//home//...//model1map.tif", outputgrids=FALSE)

Best regards, 
Kristin

Comment: For those who want evaluation statistics on Maxent models with multiple types of cross-validation, including those that use spatial partitioning of test data, check out the ENMeval package in R. The output is a table of stats that you can use to choose an optimal model, and averages of AUC and omission rate are calculated automatically over your k folds. It also outputs AIC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but based on the [source code](https://github.com/cran/dismo/blob/master/R/maxent.predict.R), it looks like Dismo's predict function does not have the ability to generate a summary map.

**Nitty-gritty details for those who care:** When you call `maxent` with `replicates` set to something greater than 1, the `maxent` function returns a `MaxEntReplicates` object, rather than a normal `MaxEnt` object. When `predict` receives a `MaxEntReplicates` object, it just iterates through all of the models that it contains and calls `predict` on them individually.

**So, what next?** Fortunately, all is not lost! The reason that Dismo doesn't have this functionality is that for most kinds of model-building, there isn't actually a valid way to average parameters across your cross-validation models. I don't want to go so far as to say that that's definitely the case for MaxEnt specifically, but I suspect it is. As such, cross-validation is usually used more as a way of checking that your model building methodology works for your data than as a way of building your model directly (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-with-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation) for further discussion of that point). After verifying via cross-validation that models built using a given procedure seem to be accurate for the phenomenon you're modelling, it's customary to build a final model using all of your data. In theory this new model should only be better than models trained on a subset of your data.

So basically, assuming your cross-validated models look reasonable, you can run MaxEnt again with only one replicate. Your final result will be a model accuracy estimate based on the cross-validation and a map based on the second run with all of your data lumped together. Depending on what exactly your question is, there might be other useful summary statistics from the cross-validation that you want to use, but those are all things you've already seen in the html output.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 2):

I may have found this a couple of years later. But you could do something like this:

```
xm <- maxent(predictors, pres_train) # basically the maxent model
px <- predict(predictors, xm, ext=ext, progress= '' ) #prediction
px2  <- predict(predictors, xm2, ext=ext, progress= '' ) #prediction #02

models <- stack(px,px2) # create a stack of prediction from all the models
final_map <- mean(px,px2) # Take a mean of all the prediction
plot(final_map) #plot the averaged map
```

xm1,xm2,.. would be the maxent models for each partitions in cross-validation, and px, px2,.. would be the predicted maps.